# Simulating Agile Software Development

Tags: agile

Looking for a guide or example of where a group  facilitator walks a group through an agile software development cycle playing the role of both the event facilitator and the key stakeholder or project owner.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5k7a9YEoUI

Comment: A good 'real life' simulation should include the stakeholder or project owner not showing up for meetings, not responding to emails and putting down the development team to upper management.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: The video is an overview of scrum, not a simulation of it. jkrankcarr's comment gets the idea of what I mean, though clearly that type of simulation would only go so far. Let me know if you have any more questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scrum Lego Game would be a great way to show the group, what Scrum is and more importantly what it feels like.

Here are two sets of detailed instructions

- http://www.agile42.com/training/scrum-lego-city/
- http://www.slideshare.net/krivitsky/lego-for-extended-scrum-simulation-1057214

Comment: +1 @Andrew Rusling: Interesting, I'll give it a try. Thanks for sharing!